# EF Add data to object containing virtual object and its foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello everyone I have the following entity:

```
public partial class Measurement
{
    public int MeasurementId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int BatteryLevel { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}
```

In another class I was creating a Measurement object:

```
var currentMeasurement = new Measurement()
{
    BatteryLevel = sensorDataObject.battery,
    ...
}
```

Then I got stuck, cause I can't remember how to handle this situation in EF. I have a reference to a Device entity, but also a foreign key to it.
So my question is, should I retrieve the Device Object (from the db) by looking up its id, and assign it as follows:

```
var currentMeasurement = new Measurement()
{
    BatteryLevel = sensorDataObject.battery,
    Device = context.Devices.Find(sensorDataObject.id)
    ...
}
```

But how about the foreign key DeviceId? Do I have to assign that too or that gets assigned automatically because I have included the object it has a reference to?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think it should happend automatically or you should configure it in the function OnModelCreatingin your context

Comment: What do you mean should happen automatically? I think I found somewhere where they said you just need to add the foreign key field. Otherwise adding a whole device entity will duplicate this in the db. can someone confirm that simply adding the foreign key is the way to go in these cases?

Comment: Sorry but it confused me.. :/ If I try to create a new Measurement object for example and assign values to it (adding a foreign key to a device) and try saveChanges() the program crashes :/ any idea why is that?

Comment: I get this error whether i add the objects that the current object references or whether I add only the foreign key.. "A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Comment: fixed it for the time being, but still unsure on the "what info to fill when adding an object".

Answer (score 0):

look at this post [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) hope it will answer your question!